# Database design for linking parent & child relationship

Tags: database-design, relationships

Currently i have requirement saying user from an UI creates there own forms which has types textbox,choicegroup etc..
Does anyone have a  any idea on how to architect the database to store all data?
If user want to link form1 to form2 etc..  how will these data links stored in database?

For example, parent1 has child1 & Child2, flow can be like this parent1->child1->child2.(In 1 single line how will parent child relationship need to be maintained in database tables)

Comment: Tables have id fields and children fields that point to this id. But your naming would be somewhat wrong here, since child2 would be a child of child1 not parent1. So basically since this is linear there are just forms following each other. So 'parent' would be 'head' or 'start' which is simply defined by the fact that the field 'parent_id' is null. So first form with id 1 has parent_id=null, first 'child' with id 2 has 'parent_id=1' and second 'child' has 'parent_id=2'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This abstract of table can help u, which I am using in my project.**

**Parent** : Equipment

**Child** : Component

**Sub Child** : Sub Component

Table 1
**Columns**
id(PK) | Parent_Equipment_Id |  Componentid  | component Order

Table 2 **Columns**

id(PK) | Parent_Component_Id |  Sub_Component_id  | sub_component_Order

**There can be one to many relationship between your parent and child table, so it is very complicated to use single table**

*Also you need to create 3 Entities for Repository*

1. Abstract ParentEntity
2. ChildEntity extends ParentEntity
3. SubchildEntity extends ChildEntity

I hope it will help you to normalize your database.

Answer (score 2):

Parent-child relationships are usually implemented in databases by having a `parent_id` column.  So, each child has a direct reference to its parent, and all the children of parent A can be found by performing a `SELECT ... WHERE parent_id = A`.

This has the disadvantage of not encoding the order of the children in any way, so if the children need to be ordered, then an additional `order` field is needed, usually of type `real`.  Thus, inserting a child at a specific point along the list of children is done with `new_child.order = (previous_child.order + next_child.order) / 2`.

Other than that, it is unclear what you are asking.  You appear to have unnecessarily complicated your question by including things about your user interface in the narrative. Your user interface considerations seem to be completely unrelated to the question of how to represent parent-child relationships in databases.

Comment: I am little confused in child ordering. can u please correct the below table :
Parent : Equipment 

id(PK) |  SchemeId     | Parent_Equipment_Id |  Componentid  | component Order 
1             |     ABC       | 0         |  11   | 1  
2             |     ABC       | 1         |  22   | 1 
3             |     ABC       | 1         |  33   |      2  
4             |     PQR       | 1         |  55   |      4
5             |     XYZ       | 0         |  66   |      2
6             |     XYZ       | 2         |  77   |      1
7             |     XYZ       | 2         |  88   |      2